# is "output" another way of saying "real gdp"?

Tags: macroeconomics

I keep hearing "output" alot and even "real output" sometimes, do these terms has to do with Nominal or Real GDP" ? because i a confused and could not really find anything useful on the internet

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the UN System of National Accounts ([SNA 2008](https://unstats.un.org/unsd/nationalaccount/sna2008.asp)),
$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{GDP}       &= \text{Total Value-Added}, \\
\text{Output}    &= \text{Total Production}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Since $\text{Value-Added} = \text{Production} - \text{Intermediate Consumption (IC)}$, we have $$\text{GDP} = \text{Output} - \text{Total IC}.$$

(IC refers to goods completely consumed as inputs during production.)

---

Notes:

1. As already noted in the other two answers, in practice, economists, journalists, and other writers often simply use the term *output* as a synonym for GDP, even though this is strictly speaking wrong (or at least inconsistent with SNA usage).

As stated in "National Accounts: A Practical Introduction" (UN, [2003](https://unstats.un.org/unsd/publication/SeriesF/seriesF_85.pdf)):

> GDP is sometimes called in economic textbooks "output" or "net output". However, output has a different meaning in national accounts.

2. Contrary to what the other two answers may have suggested, the difference between GDP and output has *nothing* to do with home production. Instead and as shown above, the only difference between the two is IC.
3. The term *real* in economics (usually) refers to whether the figures have been adjusted for inflation. This has nothing to do with the difference between GDP and output. For any year, we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{Real GDP} &= \text{Real Output} - \text{Real Total IC}, \\
\text{Nominal GDP} &= \text{Nominal Output} - \text{Nominal Total IC}.
\end{aligned}
$$

4. The term *net* (contrasted with *gross*) in SNA refers to whether (or not) depreciation has been accounted for. So, $$\text{Net Domestic Product (NDP)} = \text{GDP} - \text{Depreciation}.$$

It would be somewhat strange to speak of *net output* (this would mean we've accounted for depreciation but not IC). And indeed SNA makes no use of this term.

But again, as in Note 1, *net output* is sometimes loosely (and wrongly) used as a synonym for GDP. But this is especially mistaken and confusing because such use of *net* seems to refer to whether IC has been accounted for, whereas in the SNA, *net* refers to whether depreciation (rather than IC) has been accounted for.